# WSO2 EI, migrating all configs in H2 to another database

Tags: wso2, h2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have WSO2 EI application which has a lot of datasources and all of them are exposed as dataservices. Also, I have a lot of users that use this application. Now I want to migrate from local `H2` database to `MySQL` cluster. I need to upload all my configurations about datasources, dataservices and users to this new database.

When I made search for database files in my WSO2 EI folder I have found a lot of database files and some of them have same name.

What kind of `.db` files I should copy in my WSO2 EI folder in order to properly migrate to new database?

Comment: You may follow this documentation:https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Clustering+the+ESB+Profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [1] which explains on upgrading efforts of EI. 
[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Upgrading+from+WSO2+EI+6.0.0#UpgradingfromWSO2EI6.0.0-Upgradingthedatabases

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I understand you want to upgrade to an industry standard RDBMS like MySQL instead of using the embedded database H2, that is packaged along with WSO2 products.

All WSO2 products have the SQL scripts for different RDBMS shipped along with the product, that can be found under `dbscripts` directory inside the installation folder. We can use the relevant .sql file for creating the DB schema. Also there is no need to manually copy the `.db` files to migrate to a new DB. WSO2 setup as specified in the below links, will handle that implicitly.

Refer the following link, for detailed steps on the migration activities.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Working+with+Databases
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Remote+Instance+and+Mount+Configuration+Details
https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance520/Remote+Instance+and+Mount+Configuration+Details